# Secondary DNS causing problems after AD is shut off

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

I have two Hyper-V Servers running on a Physical Server namely WideOff-SRV-01 (IP Address 192.168.1.5). The virtual machines are WideOff-AD-01 (192.168.1.9, which is Domain Controller), and WideOff-SQL-01 (192.168.1.12, which is running SQL Server). The Physical server WideOff-SRV-01 is running a file server also. (All the above machines are Windows 2008 R2 Server)
Yesterday I configured Secondary DNS on physical server SRV-01 (which copies everything from Primary DNS of AD-01). But, When I shut down the AD-01 Server, My client computers are taking long to load after log on, I cannot access my shared folders using Domain user. Can anybody point out the issue.

Comment: Maybe you should turn the domain controller back on?

Comment: If I turn on it again, everything works fine. But, this defeats the purpose of creating a Secondary DNS.

Comment: Domain controllers perform functions other than DNS.  That is why it stops working when you turn it off.  Maybe you should promote a second domain controller?

Comment: Note that you should not make your physical server a domain controller if it is also hosting VMs.

Comment: @Greg But,  Before I create secondary DNS, I could login my client computers, and shared folders with its cached user profile. But, now login seems really slow, and can't access the shared folders. I think the secondary dns is trying to resolve the domain controller (maybe searching to internet) which makes it slow.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. The clients are querying the second DNS server for the DNS records of the DC, the second DNS server returns the answer, and the clients then attempt to communicate with that DC, eventually timing out. You can do one of two things: `1.` Remove DNS from the second server so that when the DC is down clients will just log on with cached credentials. `2.` Set up a second DC.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not directly related to the secondary DNS.

It's primal cause for the issues you describe in your last paragraph is a failure to authenticate.

Your identity information is stored in the Active Directory Domain Services database at the WideOff-AD-01.

Some theory on a very abstract level: 
*"In a networking context, authentication is the act of proving identity to a network application or resource. Typically, identity is proven by a cryptographic operation that uses either a key only the user knows—as with public key cryptography—or a shared key. The server side of the authentication exchange compares the signed data with a known cryptographic key to validate the authentication attempt."* -- see [Windows Authentication Concepts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169018(v=ws.10).aspx) for further details.

Shutting down the WideOff-AD-01 server basically terminates all network I/O, including that regarding authentication.